# How to Cache a Table in Redis

Tags: java, caching, redis

How to cache a entire table in Redis,either to cache the entire table for one single key or each row with a different key.If we cache the entire table for a single key the entire table will be returned every time even if i need a single record as my output.I am quite new to Redis caching and not clear how to cache a entire table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [Redis Hash](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-hashes), so you can index the row by its key and retrieve an element in O(1).

For example, using redis-cli (you can try it in http://try.redis.io).

Insert the row elements to the hash in a key named "table":

```
> HSET table 100 "serialized row with id 100" 
(integer) 0
> HSET table 101 "serialized row with id 101" 
(integer) 1
```

Get the value associated with a row key.

```
> HGET table 100
"serialized row 100"
```

Get all the values in the hash:

```
> HGETALL table
1) "100"
2) "serialized row 100"
3) "101"
4) "serialized row 101"
```